# Nested sort in GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm using Contentful as a CMS, wherein I have the content models "Category" and "Subcategory". Each subcategory has a category as its parent. Both models have a property called `order` which I set within the CMS to decide the order in which they will appear on the navigation.

Here's my GraphQL query:

```
query {
  allContentfulCategory(sort: {fields: [order, subcategory___order]}) {
    edges {
      node {
        order
        title
        subcategory {
          order
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The first sort works correctly and the query outputs my categories by the order field, rather than in reverse-creation order which seems to be the default output from Contentful (the newest categories show first).

However, my second sort of `subcategory___order`, which was inspired by [this blog post](https://stephencharlesweiss.com/blog/2020-01-30/graphql-multi-field-sorting/), does not evaluate. In other words, the subcategories (per Category) show up in reverse order so that the top item has an order of 8, and it decreases to 7, and 6, and so on.

For example, say I had category "Animals" with order 2, and "Trees" with order 1. My content in reverse-creation order: "Cat" (order 3), "Dog" (order 1), "Chicken" (order 2), "Birch" (order 2), "Oak" (order 3), and "Willow" (order 1).

These will come through the query like so:

```
Trees (1):
  Birch (2)
  Oak (3)
  Willow (1)
Animals (2):
  Cat (3)
  Dog (1)
  Chicken (2)
```

I can't find a way to make the GraphQL query perform both sort commands simultaneously so that my data is ordered according to the order I set in the CMS.

So many thanks in advance!

**Edit: Here's a component solution:**

Within each category node that comes from my query, I can access the subcategories and their order in an array.

```
const categories = data.allContentfulCategory.edges
    {categories.map((category) => {
        return (
            <div>
                {category.node.subcategory && category.node.subcategory.sort((a, b) => {return a.order - b.order}).map((subcategory) => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <p>{subcategory.title}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
         )
      })}
```

The key element here is how I sort the array by subcategory order within the component:

`category.node.subcategory.sort((a, b) => {return a.order - b.order})`

To be clear, this is not a satisfying solution, nor does it answer my question about how I might write multiple GraphQL sorts. But this code does do what I wanted with regards to organising the subcategories.

Comment: IMHO not supported (sorting is out of graphql specs, depends on implementation) - https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/reference/collection-order/limitations

Answer (score 2):

You are querying `category` and not `subcategory`:

```
query {
  allContentfulCategory(sort: {fields: [order, subcategory___order]}) {
    edges {
      node {
        order
        title
        subcategory {
          order
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the query above, only the returned array `data.allContentfulCategory.edges` is sorted. Gatsby won't sort the data nested in `category.subcategory`.

Further more, the second field you specified (`subcategory___order`) will only be considered if the first field (`order`) is the same. Since each category has a unique order, `subcategory` will never be used.

If it's possible for you to query for something like `allContentfulSubcategory` instead, it will work.

Otherwise, you can move the sort logic to build time instead by using `createSchemaCustomization`. I don't know what your schema look like so this is just an example:

```js
// gatsby-node.js
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions, schema }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = [
    schema.buildObjectType({
      name: "ContentfulCategory",
      fields: {
        subcategory: {
          type: "[ContentfulSubcategory]",
          resolve: (src) => {
            const subcategories = src.subcategory
            return subcategories.sort()
          }
        },
      },
      interfaces: ["Node"],
      extensions: { infer: true },
    }),
  ]
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

If you need to use `createSchemaCustomization`, see [the Gatsby docs on the topic here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/).

The docs' info could be overwhelming, I also [wrote a bit about this API here](https://www.byderek.com/post/a-stackoverflow-question--a-use-case-for-gatsbys-field-extension). It is more about field extension, but the resolver function is basically the same.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what the issue was, and for providing what looks like a really elegant solution. You may see in my edit to the question that I've found a component-based solution. Would you be able to say something about which is better for performance / practice etc, createSchemaCustomization or just sorting on the component level? Neat design on your blog by the way!

Comment: Thanks @22moonriver! I think in practice, performing the sort in component makes no difference, unless you have a significant amount of data. With createSchemaCustomization, the sort will only be performed during gatsby build, and not in the client (like with the component based solution.)